# how to get [ ] in the axis title?

Tags: plotting

I have two problems when I was formatting the plot. First, I added "Log [ ]" for my axis title but it shows as "log ( )" on the plot. Secondly, after I added the frame boundary my axis title just disappeared.

Can someone help me with these? Thanks!

Comment: Show[AxesLabel -> {HoldForm[Log[Subscript[a, SuperPlus[R]]]], 
   RawBoxes[RowBox[{"EMF", ",", "mV"}]]}, PlotLabel -> None, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", GrayLevel[0]}, 
 Frame -> True]

Comment: With a `Frame` use `FrameLabel`, e.g., `Show[Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}], 
 FrameLabel -> {StringForm["Log[\`\`]", Subscript[a, SuperPlus[R]]], 
   StringForm["\`\`, \`\`", EMF, mV]}, PlotLabel -> None, 
 LabelStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Times New Roman", GrayLevel[0]}, 
 Frame -> True]`